# Why does Views add space when putting a Multiple field content field into the same row?

Tags: views

Views seems to be adding some kind of space when putting multiple fields into a single row, but only for one field and not another. What did I do?

```
'field_item_options' => '                        //THIS IS BAD
Option A                                         //THIS IS BAD
,                                                //THIS IS BAD
Option B                                         //THIS IS BAD
', 'field_item_options_price' => '$1.00, $2.00', //THIS IS GOOD
```

1) Double checked the content type setup: Structure >> Content type >> Manage fields. They're the same:

- 'field_item_options': Field: *text*; Widget: *text*;
- 'field_item_options_price': Field: *text*; Widget: *text*;

2) Structure >> Content Type >> Manage display. Noting strange here:

- 'field_item_options': Format: *plain text*;
- 'field_item_options_price': Format: *unformatted*;

3) Show Multiple field settings: *Display all values in the same row* 
Tried this on and off. When its off, the Option B disappears from the Views array.

4) Rewrite results: *Remove whitespace* 
No effect

5) I made various attempts to remove the extra space include using trim() and using using \t,\n,\r,and \s with preg_replace() in a views template override:

```
$striped_array_options = trim($row['field_item_options']);
$stripeded_array = preg_replace('~\s+~', 'y', $striped_array_options);
```

I used the 'y' replacement character to show the changes, but at most there was at most two y's.

The end result is supposed to be a separate row for each value so I can format the OptionA to align with its associated PriceA and OptionB with PriceB with more control.

And then there's this under Multiple fields share same row 
"*If using group by, please make sure to group by "Entity ID" for this setting to have any effect.*" I don't know see how the entity ID is chosen for a group by, since "File Usage: Entity type" is the only field you can add to the View. Ah, $#@! I'm frustrated. Where is this space coming from and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Ok. I got rid of the space. I edited Content type> Manage Fields >> 'field_item_options':  **Text processing** from _Filtered text (user selects text format)_ to _Plain text_. So, if you know why, you can still get the points!

Comment: usually filtered text wraps it in a `<p>` which might explain the extra space.  best thing is to look at the source before and after.